# Upgrade flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

I update my flutter_bloc package to last.

My old code are:

```
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<DataEvent, DataState> {

  @override
  DataState get initialState => DataInitial();
```

and

```
body: BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
        builder: (context) => HomeBloc(),
```

I'm trying to change builder to create but doesn't work. And on class HomeBloc i get this error:

> The superclass 'Bloc<DataEvent, DataState>' doesn't have a zero
> argument constructor. Try declaring a zero argument constructor in
> 'Bloc<DataEvent, DataState>', or declaring a constructor in HomeBloc
> that explicitly invokes a constructor in 'Bloc<DataEvent, DataState>'

Answer (score 0):

To create the initial state of a bloc you need to call the constructor of the base class. I guess they changed the base class to provide the initial state.

```
HomeBloc() : super(DataInitial());
```